# White squares around selected words

Tags: search, highlight, visual-studio-code

When I leave my coursor in vscode at some word or select it, an awful white box appears around all similar words.
How to turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of highlighting, full words and selection highlighting.

To disable them, open your settings.json (*Ctrl+Shift + P > Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)*)

And add the following lines:

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
"editor.selectionHighlight": false
```

Then save the file and the changes should apply immediately.

Comment: The last one won't allow me to see same words without searching

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> **File->Preferences->Settings**

Select

> Text Editor

Scroll down to

> Occurrences Highlight

Uncheck `Controls whether the editor should highlight semantic symbol occurrences.`

Comment: Ok, it helped but only with one word I select. Other same words(autoselected) are still in white boxes.